# Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3

Tags: gemfile

Why is a Gemfile being created what specifies 2.6.3? How do I make it create a Gemfile that specifies 2.7.0???

Thank you

Comment: All ruby code has a Gemfile created for it. It is where dependencies are listed that need to be downloaded for your code to work.  To specify ruby 2.7.0 edit your Gemfile and either change the line that says `ruby "2.6.3"` to `ruby "2.7.0" ` (if it is not there just add it). Then run `bundle install`` and your code should work fine.

Comment: I appreciate it

Comment: woodbineone@MacBook-Pro-Alpha myapp % bundle install
rbenv: version `ruby-2.6.3' is not installed (set by /Users/woodbineone/workspace/myapp/.ruby-version)

Comment: It looks like the problem is when I run: rails new. (I think this command creates the Gemfile. Then when I run rails -T, I see: chruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.6.3

Answer (score 10):

Just change: `ruby '2.6.3'` to `ruby '2.7.0'` in your `Gemfile` and run `bundler install` in your terminal. `Gemfile` is just a manifest that contains gems and ruby version that must be installed in current folder. Here's some info about [Gemfile](https://bundler.io/gemfile.html) on [bundler](https://bundler.io/) doc.

Comment: Thank you, my friend

Comment: woodbineone@MacBook-Pro-Alpha myapp % bundler install
rbenv: version `ruby-2.6.3' is not installed (set by /Users/woodbineone/workspace/myapp/.ruby-version)

Comment: If you use [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) try to set ruby version by this: `rbenv global 2.7.0` and `rbenv local 2.7.0`. If that will not work try this: go to `/Users/woodbineone/workspace/myapp/` and change version in `.ruby-version` file.

Comment: Thanks, man. I have no idea what I use. I did this tutorial, that didn't work: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina. Then, I did this one: https://install-rails-mac.com/#comments-by-commentbox

Comment: Is your problem solved? If nothing will work just try to fully remove ruby from your computer and install it again with rbenv :)

Comment: No. I haven't got it working yet. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't know anything about this. Isn't there a system version? I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Sorry I'm necrobumping, but you can just modify the Gemfile and add `ruby '>= 2.7.0'`